# Trying to loop through a list in python and see i can match a 1 or 0 and return the value of that index location

Tags: python-3.x, loops

sample list  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

1 means occupied and 0 means unoccupied

expected output:
occupied
[0,3,6]
unoccupied:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]

```
def row_seats(seats):
occupied_seats =[]
vacant_seats =[]
for x in seats:
    if x == 0:
        vacant_seat.index(x)
    elif x == 1 :
        occupied_seats.index(x)
```

this is what i have done so far but i do not think i am approaching it properly any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could try **enumerate** to get index/number tuple pair for processing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `enumerate` to access the correct index,

```
def row_seats(seats):
    occupied_seats =[]
    vacant_seats =[]

    for ind, x in enumerate(seats):
        if x == 0:
            vacant_seats.append(ind)
        elif x == 1 :
            occupied_seats.append(ind)

    return vacant_seats, occupied_seats


seat_list = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

vacant, occupied = row_seats(seat_list)

print(vacant)
print(occupied)
```

The original `vacant_seat.index(x)` was wrong because it was trying to search for `x` in an empty list. The correct approach appends the index to the respective lists.

Using `index` was also incorrect. Even if used properly (on the original - input list, with appending), you were obtaining an index of either `0` or `1`. This would persistently return the index of [only the first occurrence](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) of those values.

Comment: This post will work. But the diagnosis explanation is wrong. The original PO failed is because it use the **index** method wrong. It's an empty list to start with - so if it runs and fails on the first **1** - giving ValueError: 1 is not in list !

Comment: Enumerate simple loops through your input list while giving you both the index of the component and the component. Check it out yourself, e.g. `enumerate(['a', 'b', 'e'])` will give you pairs 0, 'a'  then 1, 'b' then 2, 'e'. So here you check what is `x` - like before - and you save `x` position in the correct output list, the position - index - given by enumerate.

Comment: The second comparison `elif x=...` can be simplified to just `else`.

Comment: Sure, I was sticking to OPs original code. This also could have been expressed with 2 lines of list comprehensions (though then we are looping twice).